# Perforce client connection

Tags: perforce

This is a real basic question but I was struggling at it from 30 mins. I am using perforce and I want to access my colleagues workspace for accessing data report which we are working on together. How can I access his location?  He has given me the place where the file is located :

```
//datacell/nfg/depot/src/
```

I tried finding the user in the user list and was able to find it but not able to connect. I know it must be a 2 step process.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this question - hopefully a late answer is better than none.

You need to create your own 'Workspace' (aka 'Client spec', depending on which Perforce tools you are using). This maps a part of the Perforce depot to your local hard disk.

Probably the easiest way of doing this is to:

1. Run up P4V
2. Show 'Workspaces', and locate your colleagues one.
3. Right click, and select 'Create Workspace from

   In the subsequent editing panel, check the local root is where you want it.

You can then sync the files from the server to your machine.